# Alter Numeric Column to Lower Precision

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a numeric column in a table in my postgres database schema, it has precision of `n`.

I need to update this column to be a lower precision, call it `m`.

So `m` < `n`.

When I run the command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN my_column
TYPE numeric(m, 2)
```

I get the following error: `numeric field overflow`

I understand this is because I have values stored in the table that have precision greater than `m` (what I want the new precision to be).  Is there any way I can tell postgres to change the precision and ignore the lost precision?
ex.

if n = 20 and m = 15
and I have a value in the `my_column` that is 99999999999999999, this precision is 17 if I am not mistaken, can I tell postgres to ignore the lost precision and save the new value as 999999999999999 when I alter the table/column?

Comment: It doesn't work like that for numbers to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` to provide an expression for the conversion:

```
alter table t alter column col
    type numeric(2) using (case when col >= 100 then 99 else col end);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=62dd51b2b4182d8ac78fa8b5a7121c57) is a db<>fiddle.